# HttpClient.GetAsync() gives an AggregateException while fetching data on Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient, zoho

I am trying to fetch Employee data from Zoho using the URL :

```
https://people.zoho.com/people/api/forms/P_EmployeeView/records
```

using the `HttpClient`'s `GetAsync()`. While executing the code in my local dev environment the code runs smoothly and fetches the required data but as soon as I publish my code to the azure function I get an exception with the following stack trace :

```
2021-06-01T06:14:45.870 [Error] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or
 more errors occurred. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed 
to respond.))---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A connection attempt 
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)---> 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did 
not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected 
host has failed to respond.---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt 
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.at 
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken 
cancellationToken)--- End of inner exception stack trace ---at 
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken 
cancellationToken)at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
 Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)at 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)at 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean 
doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at 
System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken 
cancellationToken)at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 
sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)--- End of 
inner exception stack trace ---at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean 
includeTaskCanceledExceptions)at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean 
waitCompletionNotification)at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()at 
EmployeeDataRefresh.ZohoClient.GetEmployeeData(ILogger log) in 
C:\Projects\ZohoAttendance\Internal-Automation-and-Power-BI-Dashboard-zoho-employee-data-
update\src\EmployeeDataRefresh\EmployeeDataRefresh\ZohoClient.cs:line 39--- End of inner exception
 stack trace ---at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean 
includeTaskCanceledExceptions)at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean 
waitCompletionNotification)at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()at 
EmployeeDataRefresh.Trigger.DoRefresh(ILogger log) in C:\Projects\ZohoAttendance\Internal-
Automation-and-Power-BI-Dashboard-zoho-employee-data-
update\src\EmployeeDataRefresh\EmployeeDataRefresh\Trigger.cs:line 68at 
EmployeeDataRefresh.Trigger.AutoRefreshEmployeeData(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log) in 
C:\Projects\ZohoAttendance\Internal-Automation-and-Power-BI-Dashboard-zoho-employee-data-
update\src\EmployeeDataRefresh\EmployeeDataRefresh\Trigger.cs:line 30
```

Here's my code that fetches the data

```
using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
             = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authToken);
    Uri myUri = new Uri(_url, UriKind.Absolute);
    var response = httpClient.GetAsync(myUri);
    log.LogInformation(_authToken);
    log.LogInformation("Sending Get Request to Zoho...\n");
    var data = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    log.LogInformation("Data fetched from Zoho...\n");
    var employes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(data);

    return employes;
}
```

I get the error at line

```
var data = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I have put various log statements to debug the issue and the last log statement that gets printed on azure function log is **"Sending Get Request to Zoho..."**.
I have printed the tokens and other required variables to check whether they have correct values and they are getting the correct value so invalid token is definitely not an issue. Can someone suggest what could be the possible reason for this error ?

Comment: Has any IP restriction applied on zoho service?

Comment: @user1672994 if there were IP restrictions how would I get the auth token from zoho itself ? however if you say so I will just confirm once.

Comment: Where do you get _authToken?

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari - if you believe there are no configuration issue, then you can raise an Azure support ticket and they can assist for the right reason for this outbound connection issue

Answer (score 2):

are you expecting json response type ? and for best practice perhaps you need to supply in your header of httpclient

```
string contentTypeValue = "application/json";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", contentTypeValue);
```

and also practice

```
 httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // throws if not 200-299
```

before read result stream.

Comment: Thank you for telling me the best practices but I am sure these things wont fix the issue as I have tried them already I think its Zoho API issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here there is no issue with token or any authentication , just clear out asynchronous programming,
Frist,
Instead, by getting the value of the `response.Result` property, you force the current thread to wait until the asynchronous operation has completed, and second I will recommend

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authToken);
        Uri myUri = new Uri(_url, UriKind.Absolute);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_url);
        var data = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var employes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(data);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
```

Comment: so I suppose you are telling me to await on the GetAsync() and then do a response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; because the code you mentioned isn't correct I suppose because HttpResponseMessage object "response" doesn't have a Result property.

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari yes you are right , we have to use await in ReadAsStringAsync();  i m editing my ans but you should wait till all data fetch .

Comment: I tried that but its still having that same exception on azure function and the strange thing is now sometimes the OAuth API fails too and sometimes it gives me the access token and only the employee data API fails so I wonder if its the Zoho API that has an issue.

Comment: @KartikMaheshwari - should the statement `var data = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` need to change to `var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.

Comment: @user1672994 that things give error like
 "Error CS1061 'Task<HttpResponseMessage>' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no accessible extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<HttpResponseMessage>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

Comment: As per your code the response is declared as `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_url);`. If that true then from where you are getting `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` type?